# JSON method call is not loading

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This in my script in JavaScript,

When i call the function `calculate()` the JSON don't call method `ConvertDataTabletoString()`, do it only one time, when I load the page.

I want the method spade called every 5 seconds.

I call e vb.net function in .aspx.

How can I do?

```
    var map;
    var markers;
    function onClickRow(detailUrl) {
        debugger;
    }

    function calulate() {

        //Call the approve method on the code behind

        markers =  JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>');

        var markerlivo = new google.maps.Marker
        (
            {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.5518760, 10.3080108),
                map: map,
                title: 'Porto Livorno'
            }
        );
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Location info:Porto Livorno<br/>Country Name:Italy'
        });

        var infowindowLivorno = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Location info:Porto Livorno<br/>Country Name:Italy'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(markerlivo, 'click', function () {
            // Calling the open method of the infoWindow 
            infowindowLivorno.open(map, markerlivo);
        });


        for (i = 0; i < markers.length - 1; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].F_LATPRIMI, markers[i].F_LONPRIMI);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.nome
            });
            (function (i, marker) {

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                    if (!infowindow) {
                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    }

                    infowindow.setContent('Latitudine: ' + markers[i].F_LATPRIMI + '<br/>longitudine: ' + markers[i].F_LONPRIMI + '<br/>Data' + markers[i].D_TS + '<br/>Velocità ' + markers[i].F_VELOCITA);

                    infowindow.open(map, marker);

                });

            })(i, marker);

        }
        /*

        Dim Nome As String
        Dim I_ID_NAVE As Integer
        Dim F_LATPRIMI As Double
        Dim F_LONPRIMI As Double
        Dim D_TS As Date
        Dim F_ROTAZIONE As Double
        Dim F_VELOCITA As Double

        */


    }
    function initialize() {

        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.5518760, 10.3080108),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions:
    {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
        poistion: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
          google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
          google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE]
    },
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions:
    {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
    },
            scaleControl: true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            draggable: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            draggableCursor: 'move'
        };


        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        aggiorna();
    }

    var bool=true
    function aggiorna() {
  //      while (bool === true)
        try{
              setTimeout(aggiorna, 5000)

                calulate();

            }
            catch (e) {
                /*
                * This will happen if the sleep is woken up - you might want to check
                * if enough time has passed and sleep again if not - depending on how
                * important the sleep time is to you.
                */
            }

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Which method do you want to be called every 5s ? **calculate** or **ConvertDataTabletoString** ?

You might consider using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), for example

```
var interval = setInterval(calculate, 5000);
```

will call the **calculate** method every 5s, until you clear the interval using

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Br.

Comment: I wish JSON.parse ( ' < % = ConvertDataTabletoString ( ) % > ' ) ; It was reloaded each time the function is launched which does not happen , JSON.parse ( ' < % = ConvertDataTabletoString ( ) % > ' ) ; It is only launched the page loads

Comment: Seeing your code, markers won't update magically every call to ConvertDataTabletoString, so you should consider using a setInterval around your calculate method, and modified it for example by emptying the map first then reappending new markers every 5s (if it's the point of the app).